# How to parse through json files with nested records from java application?

Tags: java, json

I have a json file with such data:

```
"records": {
            "abc@zabili.com": {
                "user_id": 523,
                "user_name": "abc",
                "user_email": "abc",
                "time": 10747.5
            },
            "amn@zabili.com": {
                "user_id": 699,
                "user_name": "Amn",
                "user_email": "amn",
                "time": 4439
            },
            "bco@zabili.com": {
                "user_id": 320,
                "user_name": "Bco",
                "user_email": "bco",
                "time": 1927.85
            },
            "bcag@zabili.com": {
                "user_id": 425,
                "user_name": "Bcag",
                "user_email": "bcag",
                "time": 572.8
            },
            "chan@zabili.com": {
                "user_id": 376,
                "user_name": "Chan",
                "user_email": "chan",
                "time": 9769.69
            }
        }
```

I want to print the user_name and time for each user. How do i do that?

Comment: Use [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/) jar to parse json.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String jsonData = "Your JSON data here";
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonData);
for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

    // get user_id
    String str_user_id = jsonObject.getString("user_id");

    // get user_name
    String str_user_name = jsonObject.getString("user_name");
     //... for other elements
}
```

Answer (score 0):

String toBeParsed = "String Json";

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(toBeParsed);

String userObject = jsonObject.optString("records");

JSONArray userDetailsArray = new JSONArray(userObject).length()

for(int i = 0 ; i< userDetailsArray; i++)
{
    JSONObject singleUserObject = userDetailsArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String userName = singleUserObject.getString("user_id");
    String userTime = singleUserObject.getString("user_name");
    // try printing the name & time here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use gson to parse string to HashMap, like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
HashMap map = gson.fromJson("your-json-str", HashMap.class);
Collection c = map.values();
for(Object o: c){
    map ret = (Map)o;
    String user_id = o.get("user_id");
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Kaustubh Khare say, use [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/)

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(jsonStr);//jsonStr is your json str
JsonNode records = jsonNode.get("records");
Iterator<JsonNode> elements = records.elements();
while (elements.hasNext()) {
    JsonNode next = elements.next();
    System.out.println(next.get("user_name"));
    System.out.println(next.get("time"));
}
```